# Can't access to a file from Spring properties

Tags: java, spring, file, xsd

**What I'm doing:**

I'm creating an InputStream from a xsd file like this in `MyClass.java`:

```
@Value("${my.xsd.schema}")
private String xsdUrl;
...
InputStream fileXsd = new FileInputStream(new File(xsdUrl));
```

My project.properties file:

```
my.xsd.schema=src/main/resources/my-schema.xsd
```

The my-schema.xsd is in:

```
my-project
|   src
    |   main
        |   resources
            |   my-schema.xsd
            |   project.properties
        |   java
            |   MyClass.java
```

**My error is:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\my-schema.xsd
```

**Question:** what am I doing wrong? Where can I find my-schema.xsd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're using Maven. And Maven puts all your resources in the root of the classpath. So the value of your property would need to be just `my-schema.xsd`.

And then use Spring's `ClassPathResource(xsdUrl).getInputStream()` to open your file.

You might run into trouble if you run this from inside your IDE, since it doesn't run `mvn package`. Instead, it runs your binaries directly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that info. Yes, I'm using Maven. I'll try your solution and I'll let you know. Thanks!